# Creating variable names dynamically from list

Tags: python, maya

So I'm getting into using the Python API in maya and some tools require me to iterate code over various objects. This requires attaching an object reference with it's name to an object creator's output, and then running a function immediately after it's called.

Rather than running (hypothetical example):

```
className.myObject1 = mayaClass.create(myObject1)
func1()
func2()

className.myObject2 = mayaClass.create(myObject2)
func1()
func2()
```

etc..

is there a way I could say do this:

```
myObjs = ['myObject1','myObject2','myObject3']
for obj in myObjs:
    className.obj = mayaClass.create(obj)
    func1()
    func2()
```

It would certainly save a lot of typing, shrink down the script size and make things more easily maintainable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setattr()` will set a object's attribute (given by a string) to the specified value
`vars()` will get the local variables as a dictionary

Have a look at http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html for important builtins of Python

```
myObjs = ['myObject1','myObject2','myObject3']

for obj in myObjs:
    setattr(className, obj, mayaClass.create(vars()[objs]))
    func1()
    func2()
```

EDIT:
I noticed also another answer mentions `exec`. Be careful when using this in any python code .

Answer (score 2):

[`setattr()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#setattr)

> The function assigns the value to the attribute, provided the object allows it. For example, `setattr(x, 'foobar', 123)` is equivalent to `x.foobar = 123`.

Comment: c'mon, you can elaborate your answer at least a tiny little bit more

Comment: well, I guess everyone has their own style

Answer (score 0):

in addition to the `setattr()` answer by Ignacio, i would also like to mention the possibilty to use the [`exec()`](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#exec) statement. This allows you to execute strings as python code in the current scope.